# setImage in ViewPager like image shows in Android homescreen as wallpaper

Tags: android, android-viewpager, wallpaper

I want to set an image in `ViewPager` as an image shows in homescreen. In Homescreen when we swipe left or right the wallpaper also get swipe left or right accordingly. But if I set an image in `ViewPager` then it stays at one place and also image shrink itself.. It does not looks good. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Yes. Set an image as your wallpaper and set the same image in viewpager the image looks so good in homescreen when we swipe but does not look good if we set it in viewpager. It get shrink and stay at one place.

Comment: Check out the default margins which comes default in the layout.xml. Remove any margins if there are any. I am still confused what you actually want to achieve.